# What is the reason for moving the start button to the middle in Windows 11?

Tags: interaction-design, windows-os, placement

The movement of the "start button" from the corner to the middle seems to be so much hated that it was impossible for me to find any justification for it in a short search, because all the results were clogged by tutorials about how to move it back to the corner.

Having it in a corner is the best place when using a mouse, because it requires less precise aiming, the cursor can be immediately dragged to the corner without even looking. I would guess having the most used button in the center of the taskbar instead of the corner might be marginally useful for touch-only devices, but are there other serious reasons for placing it there? A cynic might say that they changed it for a misguided marketing reasons so that it "feels different", but there is surely more to it than this.

Comment: Beware of concluding "so much hated" when talking about OS adoption. Power users vs. regular users represents one of the largest vocal minority / silent majority splits! P.S. I hate it too...

Comment: I'd be curious about where "so much hated" is coming from as well.  My sense has been the general reaction to Win11 has been a giant shrug.

Comment: My opinion / urban legend is that Microsoft wants Windows to look like a Mac

Comment: The one thing I used to always be able to tell customers is "click on the wavy Window thing in the lower left corner'. Then they stopped making it wavy. And now not in the corner. Ugh.

Comment: Isn't this more gradual progress to make Windows undesirable for all possible users and uses, starting with Vista?

Comment: Users hate change.

Comment: @LukeSawczak regular, not very technology literate users hate changes *even more*... They have to learn UI once again.

Comment: @RobertF You can't* make it larger than being in a corner and still stay in the middle--reason being that if it's in a corner, two sides are functionally infinite. E.g. if it is in the bottom left, you can never go too far left or two far down, if you shove your mouse as far left and as far down as possible and keep going, eventually you will reach the button and you won't ever go past the button. Look, there's even an article about that: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jensenh/giving-you-fitts

Comment: *OK, so technically you can make it either always underneath the mouse or you could make it in 2 corners (whole side of the screen) or 4 corners (whole screen) and those are larger than 1 corner. But somehow I don't think that's the solution they're looking for.

Comment: I would kindly remind you all that the question was *"what was their reasoning?"* and not *"which one do you prefer?"*. The question is about their reasoning, even if that reasoning turns out to be flawed.

Comment: @user3067860 [Joel wrote about it](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/27/designing-for-people-who-have-better-things-to-do-with-their-lives-part-two/) ([and again](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/10/24/user-interface-design-for-programmers/)) many years before Microsoft finally figured it out

Comment: Have you considered that it's "change for change's sake"? Someone needed to put a piss mark down, but you can't change too much for reasons of familiarity?

Comment: @MarkStewart that's not an urban legend. That's so well-established that Apple hanged “Redmond, Start Your Photocopiers” banners at their 2004 conference and everybody immediately understood.

Comment: One bit of information I'm not seeing here is that the new UI design was not originally designed for Windows 11, but Windows 10X, which was a more contained OS primarily for mobile devices. When the Windows 10X project was cancelled, the UI ideas got folded into what would later become Windows 11. This is why Windows 11 has ideas has more tablet-focused ideas, and thus may be part of the UI change.

Comment: Note that a search for "Windows 10 Start Button in Middle" leads only to people asking to put the start button in the middle.

Comment: @user11153 Depends a lot on the change. If it's brand new they'll probably hate it. But if it aligns with their other devices and/or has a superficial logic to it ("the middle, that seems like a good place for finding things") it can easily pass without comment or a mild "ooh". Alternatively, one might use, I think it was, Douglas Coupland's rubric: anything invented before you're 15 has always been that way. 15-35 is new and exciting and you can master it. If you're over 35 it's newfangled and scary. ;)

Answer (score 45):

The [interview in the Wall Street Journal](https://www.wsj.com/articles/why-microsoft-centered-the-start-button-in-windows-11-11627038002) gives the answer from the Diego Baca, Microsoft's principal design director. When asked about a placement of the Start button he said:

> I do remember we wanted to make sure that the start button felt efficient, and we also noticed Windows has become more flexible in terms of the devices that it’s used on: from tiny tablets to PCs to these gigantic, 50-inch, ultra-wide monitors. And when you have these giant monitors, the button is no longer in the periphery—you need to actually travel in order to interact with the button. So we wanted to put the menu in the center...not shoved into a little corner, where sometimes people might miss it.

Comment: This is *the* answer, right?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Looks like so, although the last argument is very weak. People just don't miss the start button on the left, it's been there for decades. This looks like the usual jabber to justify change for change's sake. The average Windows users with whom I've talked seem frustrated because once they settle with an workflow, Windows change it again. Luckily you can easily change this via taskbar settings.

Comment: @LoremIpsum To be fair, when Windows 95 was introduced, enough people overlooked the button that they first added the word "Start" next to the logo, then when that wasn't enough, they added an animated piece of text pointing to it saying "Click here to begin". And that was back when most people considered 800x600 a high resolution, so the button took up a much higher proportion of the UI. With a high resolution widescreen and minimalist design, the Windows 10 button is actually quite subtle if you didn't know to look for it.

Comment: @IMSoP excuse me, but Win95 was always labeled "START", it was not a word they added later. Source: I was part of the MS Win95 launch team and ran the beta almost a whole year before launch.

Comment: "where sometimes people might miss it" - that's the answer. ['We sell stuff with that button. How can we shove it into their face better?'] - For me the start button is a shortcut to system and control panel, that's about it.

Comment: @Mazura Different people use things differently - maybe you prefer desktop icons, which I have completely disabled, or use Cortana, which I also disable. The Start menu has been how Microsoft expect you to find things for 25 years, so it's a little paranoid to see some conspiracy in making it obvious.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun, Raymond Chen says that the "Start" label was added as part of usability testing: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030722-00/?p=43083. While that's (presumably) pre-launch, that's probably where that story comes from.

Comment: telling: " where sometimes people might miss it." - it's such a terrible design that after 20+ years it's still not self-evident. But hey, let's not change it, let's make it even worse.

Comment: I feel that it's like arguing that a car steering wheel should be in the centre of the dash, so that it's the same for users who sit on the left when they drive (e.g. in North America and Europe) and for users who sit on the right (eg in UK and India).

Comment: The claim about ultrawide monitors seems odd for at least one reason: they also forced the taskbar to the bottom, which many (most?) ultrawide users find wastes way too much space. It was much easier to put it on the side. They also seem to have not optimized for multi-monitor users, either. No, based on the other decisions, I suspect it was all touch-focused design. Per my comment on the Question itself, that's where a lot of Windows 11 came from.

Comment: Every 50 inch+ monitor I've used other than for large display walls *is* touch enabled (and wall or rolling stand mounted). Having to step across the display to reach that button is significantly different than being able to reach it while you are standing on either side of the monitor.

Comment: They are losing muscle memory usage - "move all the way to the lower left and click".  My guess is that this will be reverted, or the user asked explicitly .

Answer (score 14):

**Unless one of us here at UX SE is the person who made the decision on this design, we can't really be sure.**

There is some information on design choices made in Windows 11 in this post from  their blog: [Windows 11: A new era for the PC begins today](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/10/04/windows-11-a-new-era-for-the-pc-begins-today/).

> With Start at the center you have quick access to the content and apps you care about and through the power of the cloud and Microsoft 365 (sold separately) you can see recent files you’ve been working on regardless of which device you were using, even if it was an Android or iOS device.

So it seems they are trying to achieve what they failed with Metro. That is having a design language that scales seamlessly from device to device. Which you already suspected.

Comment: Hmm, how exactly does Start being at the center and not at the corner helps scaling seamlessly from device to device?

Comment: In addition to this, Windows is still trying to push tablet PCs or 2-in-1s and they found the windows key in the corner to be very inconvenient, Inconvenient to the point where most tablet or convertible windows machine (including Microsofts surface) was already including a capacitative-touch windows button at the center edge of the screen.

Comment: @LoremIpsum If the Start menu is in the bottom left corner, and you hold the device in your right hand, can you reach the left corner with your thumb?  Depends on the size of the screen, but the larger it gets, the harder it is to reach.  You could put the menu in the bottom *right* corner instead, but then people who hold the device left-handed would have the same problem.  Putting it in the center makes it equally (in?)convenient for both hands.

Comment: By the way, although I find yours a good answer, I don't see how Microsoft's quote adds anything to the explanation.

Comment: @LoremIpsum They're saying you have "quick" access, so maybe they're referring to the fact that if your mouse is near the center of the screen, it's less travel distance to get to the start button now? Obviously not considering that if it's in the corner you can just ram it in there and click without worrying about being to the left or right of it...

Comment: @user: if you are only concerned about mice, then indeed, the corners are actually the best place to put something that needs to be accessed often, easily, and quickly, because "corners are infinitely large" as you noted, and [*Fitts's Law*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law#Implications_for_UI_design) says that elements that are larger are easier to hit. But Windows is no longer used exclusively with mice, it is used with touchscreens, pens, and even gesture recognition. It is also used on handheld devices where you only use your thumb for pointing and where the lower corners are …

Comment: … somewhat awkward to reach.

Comment: @JörgWMittag seems to me that the solution would be to place START in an appropriate location for the device actually being used, rather than arbitrarily declaring that everyone using a mouse is just wrong.

Answer (score 11):

Well, beyond the fact that there's a better adaptability for devices with a touch-pad as mentioned in the question, I see other specifications regarding design.

In the same way the question refers to the lack of justification for the relocation of the centered start button, I have personally always questioned the layout of the content located on the left.

I always had the feeling that Windows has a hard time leaving the navigation system based on the stagged of folders and subfolders from left to right. System that sometimes works and sometimes does not, and the design of the start content is a clear example. The user is pushed to follow a type of navigation from left to right, from bottom to top and then from top to bottom in each quadrant, scrolling down to see the content without knowing where it ends, a real chaos:

[image]

> When we analyze an interface we tend to think of "conventional" users who use a mouse, touch-pad or fingers. But when it comes to something more global such as a work application or even more an operating system, the design must meet optimal accessibility standards and tested to the maximum. It's difficult to even imagine the effort that a user with an [adapted mouse](http://www.quadomated.com/life/adaptive-equipment/kensington-trackball-mouse/) must make to follow the path of this diagram.

The centered design is more permissive, the lack of conditioning regarding folder-subfolder navigation and not having to align each quadrant's content to the left makes it more agile.

- There are only two visual paths, translatable in greater simplicity and clarity
- The only one scroll is no longer infinite and uncertain, the navigation dots indicate the beginning and the end

[image]

Additionally, placing an element to the left or right totally conditions the layout of its content, while the central location has more flexibility. A screen is not a book, it offers many more possibilities in terms of design, so there is no point in conditioning it with a left or right layout. In a book the layout can be subjected to the spine or the double page center. Making a type of layout to the left or right in a screen is trying to find a non-existent spine, something absurd in my opinion.

[image]

The conditions of a design are set by the designer himself, the less obstacles he chooses:

- Greater is the ease to design
- Better will be to find a suitable location for each component
- Easier will be the interpretation by the user, in this case translates into better navigability

An extreme example: there's a boom around driverless cars, but the design is still conditioned to the presence of a driver, therefore the cabin remains rectangular and the seats positioned one behind the other. If the car doesn't have a driver why are there no circular car designs ...

Comment: I don't think the driverless car analogy is very relevant. Currently there are no true driverless cars, all current cars have to support the ability of the driver to take over if necessary. But this wouldn't preclude the other seats from taking different arrangements even in traditional cars. Yet they don't because of other factors, such as having to get in and out of the car, and importantly controlling the motion of the occupants in the event of a collision.

Comment: Yes, it's a very extreme comparison, but based on contrasts, the content of the answer can be better understood. Regarding driverless cars, the design in use is not very advanced due to the conditions you explain, it's true. But even concept car designs are still very conservative. The only one that has a different attempt at seating arrangement is the [Hyundai Seven](https://www.hyundai.com/worldwide/en/ioniq/introducing-the-seven-concept).

Comment: I think the "spine" analogy is a bit overplayed. Yes, for _exploring_ an interface, being able to expand in all directions is useful; but for _repeated_ use, having a consistent _anchor_ is useful. It also contradicts your own point about accessibility: placing content relative to a consistent "spine" gives a target path for the cursor to follow. Your Windows 11 diagram conveniently glosses over the initial path taken to find the top left corner of each sub-panel, which is a _more_ complex motion than the one shown in your Windows 10 diagram.

Comment: I don't really understand your point about book spines.  Are you saying the new layout of the menu would look odd if it were displayed in the old position (bottom left)?  Or are you saying that it's never a good idea to put things at the corner?  But there *is* a point, that being that you can mouse to a corner very fast, without having to even look at the cursor.  That applies with a laptop built-in touchpad, a real mouse, a trackball (like the adapted mouse you linked), or most anything other than an actual touch *screen* where your position input is absolute, not relative.

Comment: @IMSoP: I wonder if most people actually do click.  When I'm at someone's Windows desktop, I almost always just hit the windows key (because I want to type part of a program name autocomplete-style, not browse for it in a big list).  The only time I'd browse is to see what's installed (out of programs that chose to add a start menu link), and then the win10 start menu seems at least as good, since it's usually sorted alphabetically.  The "unknown length" argument here seems over dramatic again because it's sorted.  And does anyone use the right half of start menus?  That's just ads and noise?

Comment: In fact, the more I look at it, the less meaning I can find in your comparison. Windows 10 has two columns, one has a scrollbar, the other is a customisable panel which easily could have one. Windows 11 has two panels, one with "navigation dots" which are just a different kind of scrollbar, and one which is dynamic and looks to be fixed size; it still has the old "all apps" list, but it takes an extra click to reach it. None of this seems to have anything to do with whether the whole menu is anchored to the corner or not.

Comment: @PeterCordes I find the app search in Windows to be pretty useless (typing "SCP" doesn't find "WinSCP", for instance). Generally, I use either the pinned tiles on the right, or the alphabetical "all apps" list - which Windows 11 appears to have hidden behind an extra click and given prominence to "recommendations" instead. Different people will definitely have different usage patterns though - some people still like to put icons on their Desktop, which I have completely hidden.

Comment: I am not defending Windows 9, 10 or 11. I'm only speaking from a design point of view, trying to be objective. And I insist, establishing left or right alignments in a column-based layout within a screen is a nonsensical conditioner. Obviously all this is from my point of view, free to be objected. About the diagrams, they are not casual, it's the navigation pattern: where starts and where ends.

Comment: @Danielillo Your two diagrams **are not comparable**. The Windows 10 diagram shows a continuous path, going up from the Start button to the top of the first column; the Windows 11 diagram shows a series of disconnected arrows, with no path between them. And your comment about "without knowing where it ends" is simply nonsense - both columns have scrollbars on Windows 10.

Comment: Here are some more comparable diagrams for [accessing pinned apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbEf7.png) (assuming scanning the panel, not jumping to a memorised position inside it) and [the alphabetical list of all apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31pa9.png) (I don't actually have Windows 11, but from the screenshots I've seen, the "all apps" link is top right, then shows the list aligned left).

Comment: @PeterCordes It wouldn't surprise me if mouse-clickers were an order of magnitude more populous than windows-key-users. https://jaxenter.com/users-not-tech-savvy-think-130255.html

Answer (score 1):

Without speaking to the people at Microsoft who made this decision (or reading documents published by their decision makers), no one can say for sure.  I don't even know if it was human factors engineers or *marketing* that made this decision.  It's Microsoft, after all.

I ***can*** say that I moved my taskbar icons to the horizontal middle of the screen many years ago.  My cursor tends to be towards the middle of the screen, so moving the icons to the horizontal center reduced required cursor travel distance.

Furthermore, I have performed numerous optical workflow analyses of my eye movements while physically positioned in front of a computer screen (and, separately, at flight controls in commercial aircraft).  My focal area tends to be around the center of the screen when using a computer.  As such, moving the icons towards the center of the screen reduced eye muscle fatigue.

The only downside of less eye movement is that I must be even more mindful to perform eye exercises a few times per hour when using a computer.  I was already doing this regularly, so it didn't require a significant behavioural modification.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the reasoning for the center placement given by Microsoft, and then further detailed in Danielillo's answer, does in fact make a lot of sense from a UX point of view... it is also interesting, both historically and conspiratorially, to think back to the origin of the Windows menu, and the Start button, from Windows 95.

At the time, it was considered to have been a poor (even laughable) imitation of the Apple menu, from System 6.05 (and prior), which was (and obviously still is), in the top left<sup>1</sup>.

Now that mobile devices have become much more prevalent - often outnumbering desktop devices in some parts of the world - the bottom centered "Home" button, and its Android equivalent, is now, in some respects, more ubiquitous than the left hand side placing of the Apple menu/Start button in the respective desktop OS.

So, logically (from a Microsoft point of view), it would make sense for Microsoft to imitate this center placing of the "Home" button - of these (relatively) new-comers who have finally achieved market dominance - by now relocating the Start/Windows button to the center of the screen, as well.

It would have been interesting to see what would have happened if Jobs<sup>2</sup> had placed the Home button of the first iDevices on the bottom, or top, left corner - which would now seem to be an utterly bizarre placing - in order to replicate the desktop experience. If this top, or bottom, left placing of the Home button had taken hold and gained acceptance, would Microsoft still now be moving the Start/Windows button to the center of the screen..?

Somehow, I don't think so.

*Imitation is the greatest form of flattery*.

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, Apple *did* derive the Apple menu from the Xerox GUI, but that's not the point of *this* particular Q&A.

<sup>2</sup> Maybe Jobs, ahead of his time, had *already* realised that center placement provided a better UX experience on the iDevice, than a corner placement? No doubt, in the original Human Interface Guidelines ([1995](http://interface.free.fr/Archives/Apple_HIGuidelines.pdf)) there is an explanation as to why the corner placement was *originally* chosen.

Comment: Windows Phone has / had the Start button on the bottom center as well.

Comment: Exactly, thanks... on Windows 7 (and later) devices (all post the initial iDevices), the Windows button was moved to the center, whereas WinCE (prior to iDevices) had a Start button on the left. Which backs up up my point about mimicry.

Comment: "It would have been interesting to see what would have happened if Jobs2 had placed the Home button of the first iDevices on the bottom, or top, left corner - which would now seem to be an utterly bizarre placing - in order to replicate the desktop experience." - he'd never do that. No UX person would. Bottom middle is just obvious for a button that most people will operate with their thumb on a hand-held device - can be easily reached by both right- and left-handed people.

Answer (score -1):

When screens get bigger and bigger everyday why should you be looking at a corner all day long instead of making use of your hi-res device and look straight at the middle of the screen? Seems like a reasonable decision to me. Should have been done so since Windows 95.

Starting apps has moved up from being a simple accessory to a necessity, hence the position update. No conspiracy behind it, sorry.